# How to get Code Coverage Report on Sonarqube for C++ library

Tags: c++, sonarqube, code-coverage, gcov, gcovr

I am trying to display code coverage for my project in sonarqube.
The closest I got so far is that it shows the coverage on header files, but not on source files.

**My Setup:**
I have a project with multiple modules and want to get the coverage for a C++ library (as a CMake-project). The unit tests are implemented with googletest and the build pipeline is executed on a Jenkins server.

**This is what I tried:**
I ran `gcovr --keep` or `gcov *.o` and put in the sonar-project.properties `my-module.sonar.cfamily.gcov.reportsPath=path-to-gcov-files`. (Unsurprisingly,) I got the same result for both. Sonarqube shows some code coverage, but only for header files.
In the sonarqube logs I see *Sensor gcov [cpp]* and some lines about what it does.

I ran `gcovr --sonarqube coverage.xml` and put in the sonar-project.properties `my-module.sonar.coverageReportPaths=./coverage.xml`. This gives no coverage result in sonarqube and I can't find anything in the logs related to this. However, when I just run gcovr I get coverage result for both header files and source files, I just don't know how to transfer this to sonarqube.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't use sonarqube, but did you build your library with coverage flags?

Comment: I did. To be honest I don't fully understand this and tried different flags. I started out with ```set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage")``` in my CMake file and later tried ```set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g3 -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")```. I guess this is not the problem as I get a report when running gcovr locally?

Comment: If you can get the report when running locally, you probably setup the flags right.  Somebody who understands sonarqube will have to take a look.